# Apply Linear Regression Prediction to Dataframe in Python

Tags: python, linear-regression, sklearn-pandas

I have a linear regression model that I've run, and I'm wanting to apply it to each row in a Data frame to compare the residuals with another model.  I'm stuck with how to apply the prediction to each row in the data frame.

final_df= 15 Columns (13 IVs, 1 DV, and the result from the other model)
regression_measures is a list with all 13 IVs in it

```
df_accuracy = final_df[regression_measures]
x = np.array(final_df[regression_measures])
y = np.array(final_df[['DV']])
#Create Model
model = LinearRegression().fit(x,y)
r_sq = model.score(x,y)
coefficients = model.coef_
coefficient_list=coefficients.tolist()
flat_list = [item for sublist in coefficient_list for item in sublist]
print(f"coefficient of determination: {r_sq}")
print(f"intercept: {model.intercept_}")
print(f"coefficients: {model.coef_}")
```

This all works correctly, and when I pass through a single value into the model, it works.

```
#Create a new test value and reshape it into necessary shape
x_new = np.array([3,0,1,4,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1]).reshape(-1,len(regression_measures))
#len(regression_measures)  #just confirming that it is the correct length
y_predict = model.predict(x_new)
print(y_predict) #returns correct value
```

However, when I create my function (below) to loop through the dataframe rows, it throws an error. It says "Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead"
"Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample."

```
def linear_regression_function(model,dataframe,regression_measures):
    measures=list(dataframe[regression_measures])
    print (measures)
    for index,instance in dataframe.iterrows():
        #x_new = np.array(instance[regression_measures][index]).reshape(-1,len(regression_measures))
        prediction = model.predict(instance[regression_measures]).reshape(-1,len(regression_measures))
        return prediction
        
df_accuracy['Prediction'] = linear_regression_function(model,df_accuracy,regression_measures)
```

Best case scenario would be I would finish with a data frame that has my 13 IVs, 1 DV, and predicted value.

Comment: Can't you just pass the test data as a dataframe to `model.predict()`?

Comment: BTW, `dataframe` looks a lot like `DataFrame` and `index` like `pd.Index` or the attribute `index` from `Series` or `DataFrame`s. Probably a good idea to use other names.

Comment: When you say "Just pass the test data as a dataframe", I may not understand what you mean by that.  When I tried model.predict(df_accuracy), it did not like that.

I'm not sure why you wouldn't have to loop through each row to apply the model.

Good point on the variable names.

Comment: `model.predict(dataframe[regression_measures])` (I'm quickly looking at the code, so I assume `dataframe[regression_measures]` is the test data)

Comment: Well....that was way easier.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

scikit-learn works with two-dimensional arrays of data. Therefore, if you want to submit a one-dimensional array for training, you need to convert it to a two-dimensional one.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Input

```
[1 2 3 4 5]
```

conversion to 2D:

```
arr = arr.reshape(-1, 1)
```

Output

```
[[1]
 [2]
 [3]
 [4]
 [5]]
```

In your case it would probably be like this:

```
prediction = model.predict(instance[regression_measures].reshape(-1, 1))
```